# Flash (wmode=window) disappears after calling facebook dialog

Tags: flash, facebook, firefox, swfobject, firefox6

We are writing app for facebook. It's a game written in flash and embeded with **wmode window**. We get problem with **Firefox 6**, but only on **Windows XP**. When user invoke some facebook dialog (for example: pay dialog or buying more credits dialog) flash disappears. This same happens when user click on notifications (globe icon in top facebook menu) and hold it for a while (however this is not so important).

After flash disappears it it still in DOM as `<object>`. 
This is not happen when wallpost dialog is created.

How to fix it?

We **can't change wmode**, so this way is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FB.init documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/#flash gives you some options for doing something better than displaying a white background if your application will not work with wmode="opaque".

> Adobe Flash applications on facebook.com
>
> For Canvas applications using Adobe Flash, wmode="opaque" is preferred
>   whenever possible. We have found that, on modern browsers with
>   hardware compositing, there is generally no performance degradation to
>   using wmode="opaque". Otherwise, Facebook will, by default, hide your
>   Flash objects when popup events occur, and redisplay them when the
>   popup is dismissed.
>
> If you need to use wmode="window", and would like to control this
>   behavior (such as also showing text or an image when this happens) you
>   can provide a function into the hideFlashCallback parameter to
>   FB.init. hideFlashCallback takes a state field as part of the passed
>   in parameters saying whether the window is being opened or closed.
>   This is the default implementation that you'll be overriding if you
>   provide one, but may also give you an idea of what your override would
>   look like:
>
> ```
> function(params) {
>   var candidates = window.document.getElementsByTagName('object');
>   for (var i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
>     var elem = candidates[i];
>     if (elem.type != "application/x-shockwave-flash") {
>       continue;
>     }
>
>     var good = false;
>     for (var j = 0; j < elem.childNodes.length; j++) {
>       if (elem.childNodes[j].nodeName == "PARAM" && elem.childNodes[j].name == "wmode") {
>         if (elem.childNodes[j].value != "window" && elem.childNodes[j].value != "default") {
>           good = true;
>         }
>       }
>     }
>     if (!good) {
>       if (params.state == 'opened') {
>         elem.style.old_visibility = elem.style.visibility;
>         elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
>       } else if (params.state == 'closed') {
>         elem.style.visibility = elem.style.old_visibility;
>         elem.style.old_visibility = '';
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Note: Some UI methods like stream.publish and stream.share can be used
>   without registering an app or calling this method. If you are using an
>   app id, all methods must be called after this method.

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/hideflashcallback/ for the most up-to-date documentation on best practices, including the ability to add screenshots.